# Shortening HTML content python / django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a system that pulls HTML content from a database which could look like this:

```
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>More text</p>
<p>Third Paragraph</p>
```

and when displaying it, it displays a short summary of the blog post content but right now when displaying the text, I have set a limit of characters to a number like 200 and it will cause the summary to like this:

```
<p>This is some text</p>
<p>More text</
```

Cutting off the content at any place, potentially destroying the rest of the webpage.
Is there a way in python to either close all opened tags or to only get a certain number of top-level blocks? For instance, 2 blocks would be the first two `<p></p>` tags. I have seen word press have this feature when displaying short previews of articles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to do it in a template take a look at truncatewords-html: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords-html

Or elsewhere you can use the underlying `django.utils.text.Truncator` class (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/utils/text.py#L65) that should work for most use cases, if you need some custom behavior use that code as a reference to implement it yourself.

**Update**:

If you need to use `django.utils.text.Truncator` directly, this is how you instantiate and call the `words()` method (this is exactly how truncatewords-html filter does)

```
Truncator(value).words(length, html=True, truncate=' ...')
```